# projection of point on line in 3D

Tags: c#, algorithm, graphics, geometry, 3d

I have point with x,y,z

and line direction x,y,z

how to get the point projection on this line

I tried this code

http://www.zshare.net/download/93560594d8f74429/

for example when use the function intersection in the code I got 
the line direction is (1,0,0) and  the point (2,3,3) will have projection (value in x , 0, 0 ) and this is wrong value

any suggestion 
Best regards

Comment: I tried to get the angle between the line and the plane containing the point , and get stuck

Comment: could u give me ur mail to send u sample code

Comment: If not part of NDA, you can post your current code here to public.

Comment: I updated my question with code

Comment: "The plane containing the point" is hard to define - that plane could be at any angle!  "Projection of a point" typically means *orthogonal projection*, which is the line from your point *A* that crosses your line *BC* perpendicular to *BC*.  That's a math question, not a programming question, unless you have a specific problem with your code.

Comment: @AMH: can you post the relevant code as part of the question, please?

Comment: @Dan the link contains the code I use

Comment: @AMH You realize that your example actually works and does not give the wrong value, do you? Othwerwise your question is ill-posed! Or do you want the projection along this line and therefore the projection onto a plane orthogonal to this line?

Comment: @AMH You also know you can include code into a question (which in this case shouldn't be that much) instead of using some stupid sharing site to downlaod it, do you?

Comment: @AMH: your link doesn't work in my browser.  Post the code!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to project the vector (x,y,z) on the line with direction (a,b,c).

If (a,b,c) is a unit vector then the result is just (x,y,z).(a,b,c) (a,b,c) = (ax+by+cz)(a,b,c)

If it's not a unit vector make it one, divising it by its norm.

[image]

---

**EDIT : a little bit of theory:**

Let E be your vectorial space of dimension N:

let F be the line directed by vector a. The hyperplan orthogonal to F is :
[image]

Now let's chose a vector x in E, x can be writen as :
[image] where xF is the coordinate of x in the direction of F, an x orthogonal is the coordinate on the orthogonal hyperplan.

You want to find xF: (it's exactly the same formula as the one I wrote above)

[image]

You should have a close look at the wikipedia article on [orthogonal projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) and try to find more stuff on the web .

You can generalise that to any F, if it's not a line anymore but a plan then take F orthogonal and decompose x the same way...etc.

Comment: I need the point after projection, I updated my question, I mean the new point location on the line

Comment: @AMH The new point location on the line (directed by unit vector a,b,c) will be : (ax+by+cz) . And the new point coordinate on the whole space will be (((ax+by+cz)*a , (ax+by+cz)*b , (ax+by+cz)*c). is it what you need ?

Comment: @AMH note that if you define a line just by a direction I assume that it's passing through 0,0,0 (like in a vectorial space not an affine space

Comment: @jean I tried hard to fix the problem, and posted the code, then updated it depending on ricky suggestion but still face  error, that what made me ask

Comment: If you get an error, say what the error is in the *question*, post the *relevant* code (not necessarily the whole code) in the *question*, and say what line of the code gives the error. Nobody wants to download a zip file to do someone else's work.

Comment: I didn't post whole the code , if u opened my link u will noticed that I did a simple project to simulate the problem no more no less

Comment: @rickyBobby If u can help me in that

Comment: the line direction is (1,0,0) so I projection of  the point (2,3,3) will be (value in x , 0, 0 ) and this is wrong value

Comment: @AMH why do you say it's the wrong value ? The orthogonal project on your x axis is the first coordinate of your point: (2,0,0). Otherwise we are not talking about orthogonal projections.

Comment: I need projection in all directions so I got the actual point projection, I mean the x,y, and z component

Comment: @AMH, You want the projection on a line in all direction ? The line is in one direction so the projection is in one direction. (CF formula above. ). You should have a look at vectorial spaces OR affine geometry (depending on what the problem really is). I will try to have a look at your code when I have more time. In the mean time you should try to clarify your problem and get more knowledge on the subject. The orthogonal projection of (2,3,3) on the direction (1,0,0) IS the vector (2,0,0) by definition orthognal projection.

Comment: wish you have time because I tried many times in this, also the point have x,y,z values

Comment: @AMH (2,0,0) are the x,y and z components of the projected point, y and z are just 0, as you projected the point onto the x-axis. You should really refresh your analytic geometry/linear algebra knowledge, to at least ask the correct question, as you obviously seem not to speak of orthogonal projection on a line.

Comment: I wish this answer had actual code, for programmers looking how to do this. It's bizarrely hard to just find "actual programming code" to perform what is essentially a simple trick. Everything sticks to showing the maths and letting the reader figure out the implementation from there.

Answer (score 7):

This topic is clearly old and I think the original poster meant vector not line. But for the purposes of Google:

A line, unlike a vector does not (necessarily) have its origin at (0,0,0). So cannot be described just by a direction, it also needs an origin. This is the zero point of the line; the line can extend beyond and before this point, but when you say you’re zero meters along the line this is where you mean.

So to get the projection of a point onto a line you first need to convert the point into the local co-ordinate frame, which you do by subtracting the origin from the point (e.g. if a fence post is the ‘line’ you go from GPS co-ordinates to ‘5 metres to the north and a meter above the bottom of the fence post‘). Now in this local co-ordinate frame the line is just a vector, so we can get the projection of the point using the normal dot product approach.

```
pointLocalFrame = point– origin

projection = dotProduct(lineDirection, pointLocalFrame)
```

NOTE: this assumes the line is infinite in length, if the projection is greater than the actual line length then there is no projection

NOTE: lineDirection must be normalised; i.e. its length must be 1

NB: dot product of two vectors (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2) is x1*x2+y1*y2+z1*z2